# Make levels map in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I have levels map image `.png` (Portrait) "600 x 3399".

like this

[image]

**H**ow can I put it in libGDX and make this screen ?

**My thinking:** I Put as image with position `(0 , 0)` and level's buttons with specific position which I want. Then make implementation `touchDragged` from `InputProcessor` interface. And finally modify they positions with `(screenX, screenY)` , right ??

**OR:**

```
table.add(image);
scrollpane = new ScrollPane(table, style);
scrollpane.setFillParent(true);
stage.addActor(scrollpane);
```

right ??

Any Advice ??